# how to display a pie-chart based on field count in drupal 7

Tags: count, drupal-7

I have a content type known as BloodDonors with a field, Blood Group. I would like to display the count of distinct blood groups in the form of a pie-chart. Can I achieve this without coding?

Answer (score 0):

Many options are available

1. [Google chart API](https://drupal.org/project/chart) (workes with views)
2. [Visualization](https://drupal.org/project/visualization)

You can also integrate [Google chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/) Java script version looks great but need to do custom coding.

Cheers!!!

Comment: I attempted with Google chart API but was unsuccessful. I used Aggregate settings to group by blood group value and still couldnt get my result right. Could you assist?  Thank you

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/drupal-chart-api/wiki/Examples              

http://radarearth.com/content/add-charts-your-drupal-site

hope this will help you.